# Identify if a value is repeated or not by groups in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data with many columns and rows. I would like to identify if a value is repeated (the same) for a group or not with a creation of a new logical variable.

So my data looks like this:

```
v0 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
v1 <- c("a", "b", "a", "c","e", "c", "b", "b", "e")
v2 <- c("R", NA, "R", "R", "G","C", "R", "R", "G")
dftest <- data.frame(v0, v1, v2)

  v0 v1   v2
1  1  a    R
2  2  b <NA>
3  3  a    R
4  4  c    R
5  5  e    G
6  6  c    C
7  7  b    R
8  8  b    R
9  9  e    G
```

I need to compare the values of v1 and v2 in a way whether the same v1 values take a same v2 values or not. So my output df would look like this:

```
v3 <- c(T, F, T, F, T, F, F, F, T )
dfresult <- data.frame(v0, v1, v2, v3)

  v0 v1   v2    v3
1  1  a    R  TRUE
2  2  b <NA> FALSE
3  3  a    R  TRUE
4  4  c    R FALSE
5  5  e    G  TRUE
6  6  c    C FALSE
7  7  b    R FALSE
8  8  b    R FALSE
9  9  e    G  TRUE
```

Any saggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, where `ave` is used

```
dfresult <- within(dftest, v3 <- as.logical(ave(as.vector(v2),v1,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))==1)))
```

such that

```
> dfresult
  v0 v1   v2    v3
1  1  a    R  TRUE
2  2  b <NA> FALSE
3  3  a    R  TRUE
4  4  c    R FALSE
5  5  e    G  TRUE
6  6  c    C FALSE
7  7  b    R FALSE
8  8  b    R FALSE
9  9  e    G  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers. They both worked on the dummy data but on the real data this one worked only so I indicated this one as my solution but I gave a useful answer for both.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be the following. As far as I see your question, it seems that you want to return TRUE when there is only one unique value in `v2` in a group. Otherwise, you want to return FALSE.

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(dftest, v1) %>% 
mutate(v3 = n_distinct(v2) == 1)

#     v0 v1    v2    v3   
#  <dbl> <fct> <fct> <lgl>
#1     1 a     R     TRUE 
#2     2 b     NA    FALSE
#3     3 a     R     TRUE 
#4     4 c     R     FALSE
#5     5 e     G     TRUE 
#6     6 c     C     FALSE
#7     7 b     R     FALSE
#8     8 b     R     FALSE
#9     9 e     G     TRUE
```

If you use the data.table package, you can do the following.

```
setDT(dftest)[, v3 := uniqueN(v2) == 1, by = v1][]
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I was searching for solution using group_by but could not get the last part. I tried: `dftest %>%  group_by(v1) %>%  unique(v2)` but obviously it did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Malna Pleasure to help you!

Comment: Thanks for both answers. They both worked on the dummy data but on the real data this one did not work so I indicated the other one as my solution but I gave a useful answer for both.

Comment: @Malna No worries. Whatever works for your real data is the way to go.

Comment: I think it was an issue with the memory of the computer and not the code. My data is really big.

Comment: @Malna If data size was the issue, data.table approaches may work well for you. I wonder what happens with `setDT(dftest)[, v3 := uniqueN(v2) == 1, by = v1][]`.

Answer (score 0):

An option using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dftest)[, v3 := uniqueN(v2)==1L, v1]
```

output:

```
   v0 v1   v2    v3
1:  1  a    R  TRUE
2:  2  b <NA> FALSE
3:  3  a    R  TRUE
4:  4  c    R FALSE
5:  5  e    G  TRUE
6:  6  c    C FALSE
7:  7  b    R FALSE
8:  8  b    R FALSE
9:  9  e    G  TRUE
```