# Identify if a value matches the id in a group it was previously matched with

Tags: r, database, logical-operators

I have a dataframe with data grouped by site and an id. I would like to create a new column with a logical value indicating if, within each site, the id matches the angle in a previous row.

```
other.dat <- c(1:12)
site <- c(rep(1,6), rep(2,6))
id <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.1,2.2,2.3)
angle <- c(65,250,150,65,250,150,0,240,150,345,205,100)
data.frame(other.dat,site,id,angle)

   other.dat site  id angle
1          1    1 1.1    65
2          2    1 1.2   250
3          3    1 1.3   150
4          4    1 1.1    65
5          5    1 1.2   250
6          6    1 1.3   150
7          7    2 2.1     0
8          8    2 2.2   240
9          9    2 2.3   150
10        10    2 2.1   345
11        11    2 2.2   205
12        12    2 2.3   100
```

Unlike the example given in a previous question
([Identify if a value is repeated or not by groups in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734398/identify-if-a-value-is-repeated-or-not-by-groups-in-r)), angle does not need to be unique to site for the the logical variable to be TRUE and that the first unique id will always be TRUE. For example:

```
other.dat <- c(1:12)
site <- c(rep(1,6), rep(2,6))
id <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.1,2.2,2.3)
angle <- c(65,250,150,65,250,150,0,240,150,345,205,100)
same.angle <- c(T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F)
data.frame(other.dat,site,id,angle, same.angle)

   other.dat site  id angle same.angle
1          1    1 1.1    65       TRUE
2          2    1 1.2   250       TRUE
3          3    1 1.3   150       TRUE
4          4    1 1.1    65       TRUE
5          5    1 1.2   250       TRUE
6          6    1 1.3   150       TRUE
7          7    2 2.1     0       TRUE
8          8    2 2.2   240       TRUE
9          9    2 2.3   150       TRUE
10        10    2 2.1   345      FALSE
11        11    2 2.2   205      FALSE
12        12    2 2.3   100      FALSE
```

I have tried using `df <- within(df, same.angle <- as.logical(angle, id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))==1)))` but for a reason I dont yet understand, only row 7 is returned as 'FALSE'.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can group by the desired variables, then use `lag()` to replicate the row comparison and then compare to reach the expected output:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% group_by(site,id) %>%
  mutate(Var=lag(angle),
         Same.angle=ifelse(is.na(Var),T,ifelse(angle==Var,T,F))) %>%
  select(-Var)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   site, id [6]
   other.dat  site    id angle Same.angle
       <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     
 1         1     1   1.1    65 TRUE      
 2         2     1   1.2   250 TRUE      
 3         3     1   1.3   150 TRUE      
 4         4     1   1.1    65 TRUE      
 5         5     1   1.2   250 TRUE      
 6         6     1   1.3   150 TRUE      
 7         7     2   2.1     0 TRUE      
 8         8     2   2.2   240 TRUE      
 9         9     2   2.3   150 TRUE      
10        10     2   2.1   345 FALSE     
11        11     2   2.2   205 FALSE     
12        12     2   2.3   100 FALSE
```

Comment: @maribio18 A pleasure helping. Also nice question, I upvoted it +1 so that you earn reputation!

Answer (score 1):

We group by 'site', 'id', compare the `lag` of 'angle' with the 'angle' by specifying the `default` as the `first` element of 'angle'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(site, id) %>% 
  mutate(Same.angle = lag(angle, default = first(angle)) == angle)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   site, id [6]
#   other.dat  site    id angle Same.angle
#       <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>     
# 1         1     1   1.1    65 TRUE      
# 2         2     1   1.2   250 TRUE      
# 3         3     1   1.3   150 TRUE      
# 4         4     1   1.1    65 TRUE      
# 5         5     1   1.2   250 TRUE      
# 6         6     1   1.3   150 TRUE      
# 7         7     2   2.1     0 TRUE      
# 8         8     2   2.2   240 TRUE      
# 9         9     2   2.3   150 TRUE      
#10        10     2   2.1   345 FALSE     
#11        11     2   2.2   205 FALSE     
#12        12     2   2.3   100 FALSE
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave`

```
df$Same.angle <- with(df, !ave(angle, site, id, 
         FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
```