# Drop observations if there are inconsistent variables within same ID

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 45L, 45L, 9L, 103L, 103L, 
22L, 22L, 22L), age = c(69L, 23L, 70L, 29L, 29L, 37L, 25L, 54L, 
40L, 40L, 41L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))

    id age
1  123  69
2  123  23
3  123  70
4   45  29
5   45  29
6    9  37
7  103  25
8  103  54
9   22  40
10  22  40
11  22  41
```

I would like to drop all observations for an `id` if it is associated with different values for `age`. How can I do that?

I would be left with:

```
id  age
45  29
45  29
9   37
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/59734398/680068

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat  |>
    group_by(id)  |>
    filter(n_distinct(age)==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without external packages, you could use `ave()`:

```r
df |>
  subset(ave(age, id, FUN = \(x) length(unique(x))) == 1)

#   id age
# 4 45  29
# 5 45  29
# 6  9  37
```